# Do not recalculate Tables on connection refresh

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that is pulling data from some Connection.
To the right of the dynamic data I've added columns with formulas to work on that data.

When I do a Refresh (either manually or via VBA), all those formulas are recalculating, even though calculation is switched off. This is an issue since the formulas are heavy with expensive UDFs (regexps!).

I tried Application.EnableEvents = False but it didn't help.

There's a workaround I thought about: delete all the lines from the table except the first one (so the formulas would be repopulated on refresh).
However, is there a better way to stop Excel recalculating formulas in a Table with external data?..

Comment: So you have set `Application.Calculation` to `xlCalculationManual` already?

Comment: Obviously yes ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the issue was resolved after Office upgrade. Turned out the desktop guys install us 32-bit version of MS Office by default (srsly?..)
When they changed my Office to 64-bit, everything started working as it should.
Weird but true.